# Boolean Checks Inside Settings.py of Django Always Processed as True

Tags: python, django

I am trying to introduce some checks into the `settings.py` file of my Django 1.10 project as part of adopting `django-environ` package and complying with the 12-Factor type of configuration.

While doing so, I noticed that whenever I introduce Boolean checks inside the `settings.py`, the block inside the `if` statement is processed irrespective of whether the operand is True or False.

Example:

```
import environ
root = environ.Path(__file__) - 2 # three folder back (/a/b/c/ - 3 = /)
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False),) # set default values and casting
environ.Env.read_env() # reading .env file

DEBUG = env('DEBUG') # False if not in os.environ
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
CLOUD = env('CLOUD', default=False)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

if env('CLOUD') and env('ALLOWED_HOST'):
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(env('ALLOWED_HOST', default=''))
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(env('ALLOWED_HOST_ALIAS', default=''))
```

The code inside the last `if` statement is processed at all times.

My question is whether such behavior is typical of Django's `settings` file? Why would it do this? Also, what is the best way to achieve some conditional checks based on the values (or absence thereof) loaded from the configuration file?

Comment: Why are you binding `CLOUD` and then going back to `env('CLOUD')`?

Comment: Documentation for `django-environ` is sparse. I am not sure what this line does `CLOUD = env('CLOUD', default=False)`. My best guess was that it attempts to retrieve the variable from the file and if the latter is not there, it assigns the default value of `False`. Is this correct?